# Issues with Appregnew.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have tried to use _layouts/15/appregnew.aspx in three different tenants, 2 in US and 1 in Europe, and I am getting:

Sorry, something went wrong An unexpected error has occurred.

I have used appregnew.aspx plenty of times in the past, so I am very familiar with how to use it. It seems to be a backend problem, does anyone know if this an actual backend issue? I reviewed the Office 365 Health but nothing is reported.

Best! Daniel

Comment: Do you get the message as soon as you go to the URL or after clicking Create? Working just fine on my tenant (Europe)

Answer (score 2):

After 24 hours more or less, the problem is resolved. It just works again. Our theory of a backend problem maybe was true and It was a matter of time after "some refresh" occurred.

Just to let you know with tried the App Registration in about 10 different tenants with the same set of data (Title, App domain and Redirect URL) approximately in half of them worked and did not work in the other half

Best!
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Go to office 365 admin center help desk, raise a ticket to Microsoft explaining about this issue, they will contact you within few minutes, their support desk is very good and they will confirm whether the issue with tenant service or something else(I have assumed you have followed the all steps of app registration :-)).

Here is details article how to generate app key :

[In 4 steps access SharePoint online data using postman tool](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/in-4-steps-access-sharepoint-online-data-using-postman-tool/)

Comment: Hi, Yes I did follow all steps of app registration. Just curious in your tenant is working the app registration using the _layouts/15/appregnew.aspx page? Thanks!

Comment: Hi -  I am traveling now, will confirm after sometimes. :-)

Comment: I just checked from my mobile, it is working fine, by the way it is my trial tenant.

Comment: Thanks! Now I have tested in 4 different tenants and I am getting the same error. I already opened a support case but meanwhile, I would like to know if the app registration is working in someone else tenant. Best!

Comment: Thanks again!, I still not lucky in our side, could you please kindly share the App domain and the Redirect URL that you used for your app registration? We have done app registrations like a hundred times, but maybe in the 101 time we are doing it wrong, at this time everything is possible..

Comment: It is : https://globalsharepoint2019.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePointRND/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx   -  it is there in the above article :-)

Comment: https://globalsharepoint2019.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePointRND/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx

Comment: I tried with the same App domain and Redirect URL that appears in the article, but no luck. Well, no other option to wait until Microsoft resolves. Thanks!